# A view instead of a Tableview when no item in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I would like to do something similar to app Clock.

I have a tableview which is loaded dynamically.

I would like to add a view with a text message instead of the empty tableview when no item is available.

I used actionSheet, to indicate when no item is available, it works, but I would much prefer to show a view with a text message as it is in app Clock.

Do you have any idea how to proceed?

```
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    // get the destinations data ... 


    if (destinations.count<1){

        var myActionSheet: UIActionSheet = UIActionSheet()
        let title: String = NSLocalizedString("DestinationsMsg", comment: "")
        myActionSheet.title  = title
        myActionSheet.delegate = self;
        myActionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
        myActionSheet.addButtonWithTitle("Add a Destination")
        myActionSheet.cancelButtonIndex = 0
        myActionSheet.showInView(self.view)


    }

    super.viewWillAppear(true);

}
```

This is the solution, even I am not completely satisfied with the position of the label.

```
       else {


        var bounds: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        var width:CGFloat = bounds.size.width
        var height:CGFloat = bounds.size.height

        var view1 = UIView()

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: height / 4, width: width, height: 40))
        label.textColor =  UIColor(red: 160/255, green: 160/255, blue: 160/255, alpha: 1.0)
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(26.0)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.text = "No Destination"

        view1.addSubview(label)

        tableView.tableHeaderView = view1


    }
```

Comment: Add a label to the view, when there are items in the table view data source remove the label ?

Comment: You mean add a view and a label in Table view? I am using storyboard. And when there is destination, hide the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the table view's `tableHeaderView` to your placeholder view when there are no rows to display.  Set `tableHeaderView` to `nil` when there are rows to display.

Comment: I need to invistigate what is a placeholder view. Thanks. I gives me some hints on how to start.

Comment: By “placeholder view”, I meant the “view with a text message” that you talked about in your question.

Comment: Do you refer to UITableViewHeaderFooterView?

Comment: No. `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` is like `UITableViewCell`, but for **section** headers and footers. You can use any kind of view you want as the **table** header.

Comment: You would make faster progress by actually experimenting with setting `tableHeaderView` to a label, or to a view with a label subview.

Comment: Thanks  a lot rob. it helps a lot. This is the solution to my problem even I am not completely satisfied with the position of the label. But it works.